# how to fetch data using .map() method with react Query(useQuries)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-query

I have multiple id's of array for API.

something likes:

```
const ids= [1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,
2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,
3001,3002,3003,3004,3005,
4001,4002,4003,4004,4005,
5001,5002,5003,5004,5005,
6001,6002,6003,6004,6005,
7001,7002,7003,7004,7005,
8001,8002,8003,8004,8005]
```

i'm using this id's end of the api to fetch data using .map() method.
here is my codes:

```
const fetchDetails = () => {
    const requestArray = (ids?.map(async(id) => {
       return await axios.get(`https://www.roads.com/road/api/roadControl/${id}`, myHeaders)
       .then((res) => {
        return res.data;
    })
    }))
    return requestArray;
  }
  const finalData = useQueries({
    queries: [
      { queryKey: ['post', 1], queryFn: fetchDetails},
    ]
  })

  console.log(finalData);
```

here is my output by using this codes for fetching data
[image]

so, as you can see here in output is showing me promise in array but i can't get the data. it's given me same as id's length promise.
if anyone can help me to get the data.

if i use single id end of the API
likes:

```
           return await axios.get(`https://www.roads.com/road/api/roadControl/1001`, myHeaders);
```

i can able to get the data for that specific api but when i use map to get all id's data to fetch, i can't able to view the data.

anyone can help me how to solve it or how can i able to view those data not promise.
Thanks in advance for your trying!

**S.N- i am using here false API for the purpose of security.**

Comment: you can't turn asynchronous functions synchronous by using async/await ... it's called `async` for a reason

Comment: So, What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: learn to use asynchrony - I can't help, I have no idea what `useQueries` is - especially what `queryFn` parameter is expected to be - i.e. can it be a function that returns a Promise - as a start, try `return Promise.all(requestArray)` (you can also ditch the async/await in the map callback function since it's completely redundant - i.e. `async () => { return await something(); }` is functionally equivalent to `() => { return something();}` when the only `await` is on the ONLY return statement)

Answer (score 1):

This should help you resolve your promises : [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
   Promise.all([yourpromises]).then((values) => {
      console.log(values);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to map over multiple ids to generate multiple fetches, you need to  pass the mapped values to useQueries:

```
const fetchDetails = (id) => {
  return axios
    .get(`https://www.roads.com/road/api/roadControl/${id}`, myHeaders)
    .then((res) => res.data)
}

const finalData = useQueries({
  queries: ids.map(id => [
    { queryKey: ['post', id], queryFn: () => fetchDetails(id)},
  ])
})
```